# Rails validation of dynamically created forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, validation

I'm using AJAX call to grab some JSON data and generate HTML form from it, so I don't know in advance which input fields am I going to get. Is it possible to define validation rules on the fly? I'll probably use [ActiveAttr](http://railscasts.com/episodes/326-activeattr) to define pseudo-model, but I'd like to shove in the validations once I receive the data.

So... any ideas?

Comment: User `epochwolf` from `#rubyonrails` chat room on freenode suggested me to use ActiveModel. http://www.rubyinside.com/rails-3-0s-activemodel-how-to-give-ruby-classes-some-activerecord-magic-2937.html

Comment: are you fields also unknown (i.e. you will create them?) or you have a fixed table? Maybe you could use the :if => option and so exclude certain validation rules?

Comment: al.3xa, how did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ClassName.class_eval %Q[validates :#{name}, length: {minimum: 5}]` to add validation dynamically. Of course, you need to add setter and getter for `name` variable. `class_eval` uses string, so you have infinite possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `ActiveModel` and either custom validation methods or classes should do the trick. You can't use (AFAIK) the standard validation declarations, as you don't know the fields when the class is declared.